# Pyside2 strange behaviour in hight DPI resolution

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I use PySide2 version 5.15.2.1 on windows (10 and 11)
When I ran the app on hight dpi resolution the app open but I can't do anything. I have a strange cursor that not click. ( this happen hight scling. up to 125%) .

[image]

Thanks in advence !

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem .it was because of the use of QtWin and win32gui.SetWindowLong I used to customize the windows controle bar.

Thank you.